# WordPress Admin Bar Overlapping Twitter Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: css, html, navigation, twitter-bootstrap, admin-bar

I am having an issue with the WordPress admin bar overlapping the Twitter Bootstrap (`2.3.0`) nav bar. I have tried this fix:

```
body.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 28px;
}

.navbar .brand {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 30px
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.nav-container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-tabs, .nav-pills {
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.dropdown-menu li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu li>a:focus,.dropdown-submenu:hover>a
    {
    color: #fff !important;
}

#inner-header {
    width: 100%;
}

input,textarea,select,.uneditable-input {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-form,.navbar-search {
    margin: 0 0 9px;
}

.navbar-search {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#s {
    width: 100px;
}
```

but alas it is still posing an issue. I am wondering what fixes are available?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### [How to prevent the WordPress admin bar from overlapping with your Twitter Bootstrap navigation bar.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116908/9579)

**In response to:** [WordPress admin bar overlapping twitter bootstrap navigation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87717/wordpress-admin-bar-overlapping-twitter-bootstrap-navigation)

**Asked by:** [`@TheWebs`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/27670/thewebs)

If you are using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) and have an issue with the WordPress admin bar overlapping with your navigation bar, you're probably pretty frustrated with some of these answers. I looked for solutions everywhere before ultimately deciding to just down-shift to a lower gear and figure out a solution that does exactly what I need it to do.

So here is an answer that doesn't hide the WordPress admin bar, or move the WordPress admin bar to the bottom of your pages. This answer will keep the WordPress admin bar right where it belongs... At the top of your pages.

Please note this will take a few short steps to complete, but it's worth it. It's not really a complicated or time consuming process. I just wanted to make sure the explanation on how to do so was clear and easy to follow/understand.

---

### Step 1

- Add [`get_body_class();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class) to your theme's `<body>` tag.

> Themes have a template tag for the body tag which will help theme
>   authors to style more effectively with CSS. The Template Tag is called
>   [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class). This function gives the body element different classes and
>   can be added, typically, in the `header.php`'s HTML body tag.

1. **Open** your currently active WordPress theme using Twitter Bootstrap
   directory. Find `header.php` and open it.
2. **Find** `<body>`.
3. **Replace with** `<?php echo '<body class="'.join(' ', get_body_class()).'">'.PHP_EOL; ?>`

After completing the three steps above, you have now successfully enabled your WordPress theme with WordPress body classes.

### Step 2 (OPTIONAL!)

- Add custom conditional CSS classes to the `<body>` tag.

By default, WordPress already provides a list of default classes to the HTML  tag, if you are using the `body_class()` or `get_body_class()` functions.

If you view the source code of any rendered front-end page on your WordPress website, you will notice two of the CSS classes automatically added to the HTML `<body>` tag are "logged-in" and "admin-bar".

You will also notice those CSS class names are only added to the HTML `<body>` tag if the user is logged in, otherwise they won't be added to the HTML `<body>` tag.

So if you don't want to use the default WordPress CSS class names, you can add your own very easily.

1. **Open** your currently active WordPress theme using Twitter Bootstrap directory. Find `functions.php` and open it.
2. **Add** `add_filter('body_class', 'mbe_body_class');` to the top of the
   file.
3. **Add** the following code, to the bottom of the file.

**The code:**

```
function mbe_body_class($classes){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $classes[] = 'body-logged-in';
    } else{
        $classes[] = 'body-logged-out';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Now, if you view the source code of any rendered front-end page on your WordPress website, if the user is logged in, you will see "body-logged-in" has been added to the HTML `<body>` tag, and if the user is logged out, you will see "body-logged-out" has been added to the HTML `<body>` tag.

### Step 3

- Add the CSS code to your theme.

This is the section of code which will correct your theme to display both the WordPress admin bar, and your Twitter Bootstrap navigation properly, whether the user is logged in or logged out of your website.

1. **Open** your currently active WordPress theme using Twitter Bootstrap directory. Find `functions.php` and open it.
2. **Add** `add_action('wp_head', 'mbe_wp_head');` to the top of the file.
3. **Add** the following code, to the bottom of the file.

**The code:**

```
function mbe_wp_head(){
    echo '<style>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'body{ padding-top: 70px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using custom CSS class name.
    echo 'body.body-logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using WordPress default CSS class name.
    echo 'body.logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</style>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**EDIT TO CODE**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mbe_wp_head');
function mbe_wp_head(){
    echo '<style>'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body{ padding-top: 70px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body.body-logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 46px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body.logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 46px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'@media only screen and (min-width: 783px) {'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body{ padding-top: 70px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body.body-logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'body.logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'
    .PHP_EOL
    .'}</style>'
    .PHP_EOL;
}
```

*This version of the mbe_wp_head function includes a mobile-first media query, to ensure that your header is pushed down the proper distance. For mobile, the WP admin bar is 48px tall. After the 783px breakpoint, the admin bar shortens to only 28px tall.*

There you have it. If the user is logged in, you should now have the WordPress admin bar at the very top of your page, immediately followed by your Twitter Bootstrapped navigation. If the user is logged out of your WordPress website, your Twitter Bootstrap navigation should still display appropriately at the top of your website.

Comment: Why didn't you put the css into style.css for instance, instead of embedding it into the html? It would be a more elegant solution. Also thank you for your work and the idea!

Comment: @MaxRuf You're absolutely right. Separate enqueued CSS file would be better. I was just thinking about the people finding this post, so they could easily just copy/paste. Less likely to encounter problems.

Answer (score 26):

Didn't work for me, but I found a nice fix. In your header.php use the wordpress function to query if the toolbar is displayed, and then create an empty div below the navbar div:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<?php 
  // Fix menu overlap
  if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) echo '<div style="min-height: 32px;"></div>'; 
?>
<div class="navbar-inner">
```

Comment: Great fix. I like that this is much simpler than the accepted answer and that it looks for `is_admin_bar_showing()`, not just if the user is logged in, which is good considering someone may be logged in, but turned off the admin bar. Thanks!

Comment: As of WordPress 3.8, the admin bar height is 32px.

Comment: This is a little bit Hacky but I have found this to be the best solution. Upvoted

Comment: Slightly modified solution using ternary logic and an inline style: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"<?php echo (is_admin_bar_showing()) ? ' style="top: 32px;"' : ''; ?>>`

Comment: I prefered this solution compared to accepted answer. I did a similar logic that supports the mobile height using media query: http://pastebin.com/dWxm00Hu style is in an inline tag, but you can move this to your theme's `style.css`.

Comment: This is good except on a mobile device the offset is not 32px but 46px. To account for this I used a CSS class instead of a style. Here's the class that can be applied: `.fix_wp_overlap {
  min-height: 32px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
.fix_wp_overlap {
    top: 46px  !important;
  }
}`

Comment: <?php 
    if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {
        ?>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd; margin-top: 32px;">
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <?php
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
   .navbar-fixed-top { top: 0px; }
    body.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top { top: 28px !important; }
```

if that does work for you (which it should!), then you'll have to move the  wp admin bar to the bottom by sticking the code below into a plugins folder or your functions.php file:

```
function fb_move_admin_bar() {
    echo '
    <style type="text/css">
    body { 
    margin-top: -28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    body.admin-bar #wphead {
       padding-top: 0;
    }
    body.admin-bar #footer {
       padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    #wpadminbar {
        top: auto !important;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul {
        bottom: 28px;
    }
    </style>';
}
// on backend area
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
// on frontend area
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
```

as an alternative you can use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stick-admin-bar-to-bottom/)

i dont really like using plugins because most of theme load my script with bogus codes i dont need...  solution 1 and 2 above works fine, but if it doesnt work for you, you can try solution 3 below:

```
function stick_admin_bar_to_bottom_css() {
echo "

html {
padding-bottom: 28px !important;
}

body.admin-bar {
margin-top: -28px;
}

#wpadminbar {
top: auto !important;
bottom: 0;
}

#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul {
bottom: 28px;
}

";
}

add_action('admin_head', 'stick_admin_bar_to_bottom_css');
add_action('wp_head', 'stick_admin_bar_to_bottom_css');
```

That seemed to work for me fine without the 28px issues..

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work for me until I added this to the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

Fix for Bootstrap 2 & 3 `navbar-fixed-top` to prevent overlapping of site menu with WordPress admin menu

```
.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top {
  top:46px;
  @media screen and (min-width:782px) {
    top:32px;
  }
}
```

Fix for Bootstrap 4 `fixed-top` to prevent overlapping of site menu with WordPress admin menu

```
.admin-bar .fixed-top {
  top:46px;
  @media screen and (min-width:782px) {
    top:32px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! Just what I was looking for, however, I did something a little differently in step 3. Not sure that it matters but my code looks like this...

```
    function mbe_wp_head(){
    echo '<style>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'body{ padding-top: 70px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using custom CSS class name.
    echo 'body.body-logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using WordPress default CSS class name.
    echo 'body.logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</style>'.PHP_EOL;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mbe_wp_head');
```

You mentioned adding in different places, but I have always done it like this and it seems to work just fine. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: And what exactly did you do different?