# Customize Wordpress admin-bar

Tags: admin-bar

I would like to move the admin panel which is shown when I am on my website, not the one in the dashboard.

Now it is as usual, at the top but it is interacting with my fixed navigation, hiding it partially. So I would like to put it to the right site vertically. Is there a setting somewhere to do this or do I have to use CSS?

Comment: There is no setting for moving admin bar on right side. You will have to use css/js.

Comment: [This may help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87717/wordpress-admin-bar-overlapping-twitter-bootstrap-navigation/140296)

Comment: I have a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-bar-button/) that you may find helpful.  It can't make the admin bar vertical, but you can position it at the bottom of the screen instead of the top if you wish, and it replaces the bar with a less intrusive button (although the user can choose to shoe the full bar at any time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting of putting the admin function vertically but if its a nuisance you can choose to not to display it by adding this filter to your functions.php file. The admin bar will be hidden in the frontpage but will be visible in the dashboard

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

When you are working you can also hide it temporarily using firebug. Just select the div 
     #wpadminbar and apply the visibility CSS rule :

```
visibility:hidden;
```

This is not a permanent thing it just helps you to visualize the fixed menu hidden beneath your admin bar.

Comment: Thank you Njengah for that alternative solution. Although I would like to display the admin bar and since people use that page who are not familiar with firebug I will use your solution for my own website someday maybe.